# What is this syntax in front of the Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking at Stripe examples and came across something I've never used before what is this part called so I can read up on it?

```
<{}, {stripe: null | StripeShape}>
```

below is the full example I was looking at.

```
export class App extends React.Component<{}, {stripe: null | StripeShape}> {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      stripe: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // componentDidMount only runs in a browser environment.
    // In addition to loading asynchronously, this code is safe to server-side render.

    // You can inject a script tag manually like this,
    // or you can use the 'async' attribute on the Stripe.js v3 <script> tag.
    const stripeJs = document.createElement('script');
    stripeJs.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';
    stripeJs.async = true;
    stripeJs.onload = () => {
      // The setTimeout lets us pretend that Stripe.js took a long time to load
      // Take it out of your production code!
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          stripe: window.Stripe('pk_test_...'),
        });
      }, 500);
    };
    document.body && document.body.appendChild(stripeJs);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StripeProvider stripe={this.state.stripe}>
        <Checkout />
      </StripeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The `SomeIdentifier<Angle, Brackets>` syntax is called "generics" and it's commonly used in typed languages.  Stripe is using either TypeScript or FlowType in their code base and taking advantage of the typings available for either checker for React to say that this component has no props (`{}`) and its state has a single key (`stripe`) which may be either `null` or in a `StripeShape`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the following code:

```
interface SearchBarProps {
  term: string;
  optionalArgument?: string;
}

interface SearchBarState{
  something: number;
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component<SearchBarProps, SearchBarState> {
  constructor(props: SearchBarProps){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      something: 23
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {something} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>{something}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

In `class SearchBar extends React.Component<SearchBarProps, SearchBarState> {`, `SearchBarProps` and `SearchBarState` denote type of expected props and type of state for component `SearchBar` respectively. You must give propTypes and stateType when you use typescript.
 
You can avoid giving types by using keyword `any` but I highly suggest you not to follow this "evil" path if you truly want to take advantage of using typescript.

In interface `SearchBarProps`, `optionalArgument` becomes an optional argument as we add a question mark `?` in front of it, so `<SearchBar term='some term' />` won't show any error even if you don't pass `optionalArgument` explicitly.
Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at flow types:

https://flow.org/

It is a static type checker developed by Facebook that allows you to type your JavaScript objects